# connection error outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, class, object, connection

I can't create any connection of objects in my class, is there any way to see how the objects are connected in my class?. The Xcode gives me this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<VistaInicio 0x68879e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myButton.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `myButton` outlet in the `VistaInicio` class. Yet something in some xib is connected to it (probably it was connected before you removed this outlet). You need to go through your Interface Builder files and remove the broken connection.